# PHP script does nothing. How to debug?

Tags: php, remote-debugging

I have a script which does exactly nothing. It does not even return an echo in the first line of the script??

All my other scripts work, they are similar, have the same permissions and are in the same folder.

It runs in a webspace remotely. How can I debug this?

Answer (score 2):

Put below line on the top of the your script.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Which will show you if there is any error in the script.

Answer (score 1):

Check your php.ini settings.

Inside your **php.ini**:

```
display_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

then restart your web server and try again.

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort, ( as others mentioned the preferred ways )

You can comment all the code out, and back track the code tell it stops, just be mindful of if{ } blocks and other control structures.
For example.. say you have this code.

```
<?php

function do_nothing(){

}

$somthing = 1;
if($something){
  do_nothing();
}

$badCode = 'hello'

$array = array(1,2,3,4,5);

foreach($array as $item ){
   echo 'item: '.$item;
}
```

outputs nothing, because it's broken.

You could

```
<?php
/*
function do_nothing(){

}

$somthing = 1;
if($something){
  do_nothing();
}

$badCode = 'hello'

$array = array(1,2,3,4,5);

foreach($array as $item ){
   echo 'item: '.$item;
}
*/
echo 'works';
```

outputs

```
'works'
```

And continue to

```
<?php
/*
function do_nothing(){

}

$somthing = 1;
if($something){
  do_nothing();
}

$badCode = 'hello'
*/
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5); //need this for the loop
foreach($array as $item ){
 //don't comment half this block
   echo 'item: '.$item;
}

echo 'works';
```

Outputs

```
'item: 1'

'item: 2'

'item: 3'

'item: 4'

'item: 5'

'works'
```

And finally

```
<?php
/*
function do_nothing(){

}

$somthing = 1;
if($something){
  do_nothing();
}
*/
$badCode = 'hello'

$array = array(1,2,3,4,5); //need this for the loop
foreach($array as $item ){
 //don't comment half this block
   echo 'item: '.$item;
}

echo 'works';
```

Broken, ( missing semicolon $badCode = 'hello'; )

It's a rudimentary way to debug, to be sure. but it will work 100% of the time if you respect the control blocks..

Also be sure to be familiar with the different print functions.

- echo — Output one or more strings
- print_r — Prints human-readable information about a variable
- var_export — Outputs or returns a parsable string representation of a variable
- var_dump — Dumps information about a variable
- debug_backtrace — Generates a backtrace

I'm sure there are more of these but those are the most common.  Its also useful to use a `<pre>`
tag before printing objects and array to preserve the whitespace and make them easy to read.

I also like to use this little function ( which can tell you what line you printed from )

```
/**
 * export a variable with line number from backtrace using offset
 * @param mixed $var
 * @param int $offset
 */
function print_debug($var=null, $offset=0){
    $stacktrace = debug_backtrace(false);
    $trace = $stacktrace[$offset];
    extract($trace);
    echo "<span style='color: #CCC;'> Output from FILE[ $file ] LINE[ $line ]</span>";
    echo "<pre>";
    var_export($var);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Being a programmer, knowing to use a debugging tool is a handy. 
I suggest you to use [xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/)